# Cron email not sent by sSMTP if job takes > 5 minutes

Tags: cron, ssmtp

We have two servers, one of which runs Ubuntu and the other Amazon Linux 2. Both run a series of cron jobs for different clients.

The Ubuntu server sends an email (to a group email address) with the output of every cron job. There is no output redirection: just a command to execute, for each entry:

```
0 2 * * * /apps/ourapp/sync_data -c variable1 -s all -i CLIENT1
```

... repeated with different times and different values for `-i`. 
The scheduled start time is always of the form
*hh***:00**, *hh***:15** or *hh***:45**.

It works satisfactorily: people get the email.

This isn't the case with the Amazon Linux machine.  Its mail log has entries like this (slightly redacted):

```
Feb 28 07:05:04 ip-XXXX sSMTP[32212]: Connection lost in middle of processing
Feb 28 08:05:04 ip-XXXX sSMTP[32382]: killed: timeout on stdin while reading body -- message saved to dead.letter.
Feb 28 08:05:04 ip-XXXX sSMTP[32382]: Timeout on stdin while reading body
Feb 28 21:50:04 ip-XXXX sSMTP[2261]: killed: timeout on stdin while reading body -- message saved to dead.letter.
Feb 28 21:50:04 ip-XXXX sSMTP[2261]: Timeout on stdin while reading body
Feb 28 22:05:04 ip-XXXX sSMTP[2505]: killed: timeout on stdin while reading body -- message saved to dead.letter.
Feb 28 22:05:04 ip-XXXX sSMTP[2505]: Timeout on stdin while reading body
Feb 28 22:20:05 ip-XXXX sSMTP[2845]: killed: timeout on stdin while reading body -- message saved to dead.letter.
Feb 28 22:20:05 ip-XXXX sSMTP[2845]: Timeout on stdin while reading body
```

You'll note that the timestamp minute components are 5 min past either the hour, the 15 minute, or the 45 minute mark. These correspond to cron jobs that *aren't* sending email.

`dead.letter` is always empty, which makes sense if the log doesn't get sent until the job ends (as I infer happens.)

What I've read about `sSMTP` suggests that you can't override the `stdin` timeout with config options (though that information may be out of date).

So what can I do? Is this because we're using `sSMTP` rather than some other mail mechanism?

Comment: We are not able to guess how a custom made application behaves, much less without any source code, logs or debugging in the question. I also suspect from the question there might be wrong expectation of this group, we are slanted through clarifying Linux know how, not debugging unknown applications behaviour.

Comment: (1) Please verify my edit and roll it back (or correct it) if it’s wrong.  (2) I don’t understand why the `dead.letter` files are empty.  If you believe that you do, please clarify your explanation.

Comment: [Debian has the source for sSMTP](https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/ssmtp) M. Ribeiro, [and manuals too](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/ssmtp/index.html).

Comment: The questioner is asking about sSMTP.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro JdeBP is correct: I was asking about sSMTP, where the stdin input was coming from a cron job's stdout. But I do see that the way I structured the question was misleading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing that you can do if you stick with sSMTP.  As you surmised, this is not configurable.  The 5 minute timeout is [hardwired into the code of the program](https://sources.debian.org/src/ssmtp/2.64-8/ssmtp.h/#L13).  If your job takes more than 5 minutes, then you will simply need a different mail submission system.